# Convert duplicate dictionary items to unique items with array of IDs

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, with one of the dictionary values `name` containing duplicate data that I want to normalize. The list looks like this:

```
[
    {'name': 'Craig McKray', 'document_id': 50, 'annotation_id': 8}, 
    {'name': 'None on file', 'document_id': 40, 'annotation_id': 5},
    {'name': 'Craig McKray', 'document_id': 50, 'annotation_id': 9},
    {'name': 'Western Union', 'document_id': 61, 'annotation_id': 11}
]
```

What I want to do is create a new dictionary that contains only unique names. But I need to track the document_ids and annotation_ids. Sometimes the document_ids are the same but I only need to track them as associated to a name. So the above list would turn into:

```
[
     {'name': 'Craig McKray', 'document_ids': [50], 'annotation_ids': [8, 9]},
     {'name': 'None on file', 'document_ids': [40], 'annotation_id': [5]},
     {'name': 'Western Union', 'document_ids': [61], 'annotation_ids': [11]}
]
```

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
result = []
# resolve duplicate names
result_row = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    for double in data:
        if item['name'] == double['name']:
            result_row['name'] = item['name']
            result_row['record_ids'].append(item['document_id'])
            result_row['annotation_ids'].append(item['annotation_id'])
            result.append(result_row)
```

The main problem with the code is I am comparing and finding the duplicates, but when I iterate to the next item, it finds the duplicate again creating somewhat of an infinite loop. How can I edit the code so it does not keep comparing the duplicates over and over?

Comment: Please post the output you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new = dict()
for x in people:
    if x['name'] in new:
        new[x['name']].append({'document_id': x['document_id'], 'annotation_id': x['annotation_id']})
    else:
        new[x['name']] = [{'document_id': x['document_id'], 'annotation_id': x['annotation_id']}]
```

It's not *exactly* what you're asking for, but the format should do what you're trying to do.

This is the output:

```
{'Craig McKray': [{'annotation_id': 8, 'document_id': 50}, {'annotation_id': 9, 'document_id': 50}], 'Western Union': [{'annotation_id': 11, 'document_id': 61}], 'None on file': [{'annotation_id': 5, 'document_id': 40}]}
```

Here, I think this might be better for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict
new = defaultdict(dict)

for x in people:
    if x['name'] in new:
        new[x['name']]['document_ids'].append(x['document_id'])
        new[x['name']]['annotation_ids'].append(x['annotation_id'])
    else:
        new[x['name']]['document_ids'] = [x['document_id']]
        new[x['name']]['annotation_ids'] = [x['annotation_id']]
```

Comment: This works great but how does defaultdict work in this scenario? For my own education.

Comment: We need a defaultdict with dict as the default so that we can add the `annotation_ids` key to it and then assign a list to it.

Answer (score 0):

A more functional `itertools.groupby` approach could be this. It's a tad cryptic, so I'll explain.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

inp = [
    {'name': 'Craig McKray', 'document_id': 50, 'annotation_id': 8}, 
    {'name': 'None on file', 'document_id': 40, 'annotation_id': 5},
    {'name': 'Craig McKray', 'document_id': 50, 'annotation_id': 9},
    {'name': 'Western Union', 'document_id': 61, 'annotation_id': 11}
]

def groupvals(vals):

    namegetter = itemgetter('name')
    doccanngetter = itemgetter('document_id', 'annotation_id')

    for grouper, grps in groupby(sorted(vals, key=namegetter), key=namegetter):

        docanns = [set(param) for param in zip(*(doccanngetter(g) for g in grps))]
        yield {'name': grouper, 'document_id': list(docanns[0]), 'annotation_id': list(docanns[1])}


for result in groupvals(inp):
    print(result)
```

To use `groupby`, you need a sorted list. So first sort by name. then `groupby` name. Next you can pull out the `document_id` and `annotation_id` parameters and zip them. This has the effect of putting all the `document_ids` in a list and all the `annotation_id`s in another. You can then call `set` to remove duplicates and use a generator to yield each element as a `dict`.

I used a generator, as it avoids the need to build up a result list. Although you could do that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

My take on the subject:

```
result = []
# resolve duplicate names
all_names = []
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    if item['name'] in all_names:
        continue
    result_row = {'name': item['name'], 'record_ids': [item['document_id']],
                  'annotation_ids':[item['annotation_id']]}
    all_names.append(item['name'])
    for j, double in enumerate(data):
        if item['name'] == double['name'] and i != j:
            result_row['record_ids'].append(double['document_id'])
            result_row['annotation_ids'].append(double['annotation_id'])
        result.append(result_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
from collections import defaultdict

catalog = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for d in dicts:
    entry = catalog[d['name']]
    for k in set(d) - {'name'}:
        entry[k].append(d[k])
```

Pretty print

```
>>> for name, e in catalog.items():
>>>     print "'{0}': {1}".format(name, e)

'Craig McKray': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'annotation_id': [8, 9], 'document_id': [50, 50]})
'Western Union': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'annotation_id': [11], 'document_id': [61]})
'None on file': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'annotation_id': [5], 'document_id': [40]})
```